# How to supply username password in Spring Camel ActiveMQ configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am creating following bean , the property file has following property

1. activemq.broker-url=ssl://myamqdomain.com:61617
2. activemq.broker-user=user
3. activemq.broker-pwd=pwd

but when I inspected *connectionFactory* I see that url is fine but user name and password is including **=**
why is this happening?

the workaround I found was in URL itself I included the username and password it's working

```
@Bean
    public JmsTransactionManager creatUeJmsTransactionManager(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();

        jmsTransactionManager.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        return jmsTransactionManager;
    }
```

Comment: It is `spring.activemq.user` and `spring.activemq.password`

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, the [spring-boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html) mentions to simply declare the following properties in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=secret

# mentioning the broker-url for a working sample
spring.activemq.broker-url=ssl://myamqdomain.com:61617
```

Alternatively, if you have a `application.yml` file, you can declare them like this:

```
spring:
  activemq:
    brooker-url: ssl://myamqdomain.com:61617
    user: admin
    password: secret
```

Either way you choose, this should fix your issue.

Remember with `spring-boot` you do not really need to declare the beans as the framework does it for you, there are special cases like connecting to two brokers where you would need to declare a `@Configuration` bean but it seems not to be the case for a simple use-case like yours.